# What data types to use when dealing with significant small numbers(10E-9) and big numbers (10E+8) to perform an algebraic equation in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Below is a simplified version of my code. I have defined the following data types for the variables I am using to perform an algebraic equation ("hexsimvalue"). At the moment, I get an error saying "invalid data type"

```
sub test()

    Dim simvalue As Long, hexsimvalue As Single, resolution As Single, vDB

    With Sheet1
        vDB = .Range("a1").CurrentRegion 'Get data to array from excel data range
        n = UBound(vDB, 1) 'Size of array (row of 2 dimension array)
    End With

    For i = 2 To n
    resolution = vDB(i, 5)
    simvalue = vDB(i, 13)

    'Algebraic equation:
    hexsimvalue = Round(Hex((simvalue) / resolution), 0)

    next i

end sub
```

[image: picture of the data in excel:]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: Bonus for hand drawn column identifiers but I would have taken back ½ for supplying an image instead of copy&paste data if I could. (and yes, anything less than 15 **significant** digits is probably best served by a **double**)

Comment: Round doesn't take hexadecimals; it takes integers which include both long and short integers. Why are you trying to convert the values to hex before calculating the result?

Comment: I think Hex() returns a string and Round can't round a string.

Comment: Why are you trying to apply *ROUND()* to a **String**?

Comment: @jsotola, the line  "hexsimvalue = Round(Hex((simvalue) / resolution), 0)" has the error

Comment: @Jeeped, I also tried it with  "hexvalue = simvalue / resolution" by itself but it outputs just zeros

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Thank you for that catch. Now, I just tried to use `hexvalue = simvalue / resolution` but for some reason it just outputs 0

Comment: I took your suggestions and have tried this:  `hexsimvalue = Hex(Round((simvalue / resolution), 0))`  However, it gives me an error saying "Overflow" in that line

Comment: put in a breakpoint after `vDB` gets assigned and examine `vDB` in the watch window     .....  note: to  make your code cleaner, get rid of the `with` command and use `vDB = Sheet1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion`

Comment: @jsotola, Thank you for the suggestions. I will try it

Comment: @jsotola, It gives the "overflow" error when the Resolution=8.3819E-08 and it stops there

Comment: The issue that I am seeing is that if I input simvalue = 1000 and resolution = 8.3918E-08 in the excel spreadsheet columns, It gives me the "overflow" error.

Comment: Did you change resolution and simvalue to doubles or decimals instead of singles?

Comment: @mooseman, I did and it still produce the error...

Comment: Seems that HEX() is having a problem with the 11 digit number, while a 10 digit number works fine.   Also, you don't have to round the number first, since HEX does that as part of its function.

Comment: @mooseman, thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
Sub test()

    Dim simvalue As Long, hexsimvalue As String, resolution As Single, vDB

    With Sheet1
        vDB = .Range("a1").CurrentRegion 'Get data to array from excel data range
        n = UBound(vDB, 1) 'Size of array (row of 2 dimension array)
    End With

    For i = 2 To n
    resolution = vDB(i, 5)
    simvalue = vDB(i, 13)

    'Algebraic equation:
    hexsimvalue = MyHex(Round((simvalue) / resolution, 0))

    Next i

End Sub
```

The error seems to happen because you are trying to store a Hex value like **186A00** in a **Single** variable so if you change its type to **string** It should work

### Edit

You are having an overflow error because of the "Hex" function so you will need to make a function to convert from decimal to hex. I will post a function I found.

```
Private Function MyHex(ByVal TempDec As Double) As String
    Dim TNo As Integer
    MyHex = ""
    Do
        TNo = TempDec - (Fix(TempDec / 16) * 16)
        If TNo > 9 Then
            MyHex = Chr(55 + TNo) & MyHex
        Else
            MyHex = TNo & MyHex
        End If
        TempDec = Fix(TempDec / 16)
    Loop Until (TempDec = 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually already tried that. The issue now is that if I input a simvalue = 1000 and resolution = 8.3918E-08   It gives me the "overflow" error....

Answer (score 2):

These are your best bets for precision

Decimal         16 bytes
0 through +/-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 (+/-7.9...E+28) † with no decimal point; 0 through +/-7.9228162514264337593543950335 with 28 places to the right of the decimal;
smallest nonzero number is +/-0.0000000000000000000000000001 (+/-1E-28)

Double (double-precision floating-point)        8 bytes
-1.79769313486231570E+308 through -4.94065645841246544E-324 † for negative values;
4.94065645841246544E-324 through 1.79769313486231570E+308 † for positive values

Comment: Thank you for the info. For the above example, do you have any suggestions of why I am getting the error "Type Mismatch"? I am sure I am using the data types wrong but I have also tried double and does not work...

Comment: As the others here have told you, using the HEX function returns a string and you are trying to round that value, so that's where you get a type mismatch.

Comment: I have tried this: `hexsimvalue = Hex(Round((simvalue / resolution), 0))` However, it gives me an error saying "Overflow" in that line

Comment: The issue that I am seeing is that if I input simvalue = 1000 and resolution = 8.3918E-08 in the excel spreadsheet, It gives me the "overflow" error.